# How can i store decals in Three.js and load them?

Tags: three.js

I have a model that when i click on the faces - it's adds decals (points or marks on the face) , i wonder how can i store the selection and load it later on.

I've followed the example [Here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals) and this is then function that stores the decal in array

```
    function shoot() {

        position.copy( intersection.point );
        orientation.copy( mouseHelper.rotation );

        if ( params.rotate ) orientation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

        var scale = params.minScale + Math.random() * ( params.maxScale - params.minScale );
        size.set( scale, scale, scale );

        var material = decalMaterial.clone();
        material.color.setHex( 0xffffff );

        var m = new THREE.Mesh( new DecalGeometry( mesh, position, orientation, size ), material );

        decals.push( m );
        scene.add( m );

    }
```

So i've tried to store the decals array and when the scene is loading - add them to the scene

```
scene.add( decals ); // just an idea
```

I also run in to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zrq6unge/1/) example - but still - i couldn't figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Since decals are just meshes, you can serialize them with `Object3D.toJSON()` and restore them via `ObjectLoader`. I've update your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugc5dhkx/) to demonstrate this approach. The relevant code is:

```js
const jsonString = JSON.stringify( scene.toJSON() );
scene = new THREE.ObjectLoader().parse( JSON.parse( jsonString ) );
```

When the scene object is restored, the decals should still be there. The only thing that disappears is the axes helper (since helpers can't be serialized/deserialized yet).

Comment: Thanks - i guess something i wrong with serialising the  jsonString - be cause - when i store it (in localStorage for example) it's broken - did you succeed reloading it?